# unable to get id from URL php

Tags: php, html

I want to get the id when pressing a button in order to delete an item from a session. The id appears in the URL but i'm not able to get it using $_GET.

```
<form action="Shop.php?id= <?php echo $values["ProductCode"]; ?>" method= "post">
<input type= "submit" name="remove" value= "Remove" class= "btn btn-danger">

</form>
```

```
if(isset($_POST['remove'])){

foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values){
if($values["ProductCode"] == $_GET['id']){

unset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys]);
echo '<script>alert("Item Removed")</script>';
echo '<script>window.location="Shop.php"</script>';
```

Comment: Try removing the space `<form action='Shop.php?id=<?php echo $values["ProductCode"];?>' method= 'post'>`

Comment: Thank you so much my problem is solved thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space between `id=` and `<?php echo $values["ProductCode"];?>`

```
<form action='Shop.php?id=<?php echo $values["ProductCode"];?>' method='post'>
```